# How to associate Buttons with the parent view and announce to the user with TalkBack?

Tags: android, talkback

I'm trying to make TalkBack work for my Android app, in my app layout I have a list of CardViews inside a RecyclerView, each CardView contains several TextViews and several Buttons: [App layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRRup.png)

When I turn on Android TalkBack, and tap on a CardView, TalkBack announces all the TextViews, but doesn't announce any Button. If I continue swiping right, the buttons will gain focus one by one. Not sure if my understanding is correct, but seems like TalkBack treats TextViews and Buttons differently because the buttons are focusable.

Is there a way to make TalkBack announce all content on the CardView (TextViews and Buttons) and keep the Buttons focusable (so I'll still be able to set focus on Buttons by swiping)?

PS:

One solution that worked is to directly set a content description on the CardView, and make the content description contain all content of TextViews and Buttons, but that's kind of hacky, so I'm trying to find a better solution here.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A button is actionable.  If you want your users to be able to do the actions of each button, they need to be separately focusable.  If they aren't actionable, they shouldn't be buttons.

Comment: I guess this is the intended behavior of TalkBack then. I'll just let it be. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you've described is expected and your solution is the correct one.

For ViewGroups with no explicit content description, TalkBack will attempt to infer one from the children, by concatenating the content description (or text value if view extends from TextView) of all the children.

Since the buttons themselves are actionable (focusable/clickable), they are not included in the inferred content description.

Setting an explicit content description on the card is the correct approach to take - your goal should be to describe the information that the card represents. IMO, it should not contain the description for the buttons since they will be separately focusable and will be read aloud when the user focuses on them.

---

The best approach IMO is to hide the buttons if TalkBack is enabled, and to present the cards as entities that contain a single action and a single, explicitly-set content description.

It's important not to reduce functionality for TalkBack users - all the user goals that were achievable should still be achievable; there is no requirement that the goals must be achieved in the same way by all users. So in this case, you could make the card's primary action as the click action, and offer the actions from the buttons in another place in the app.

One pattern which works well is to display a dialog on click, and this contains all the actions. This has a couple of benefits:

- the card is single action so navigating between cards is single-swipe only
- the default dialog is accessible by default - no extra work needed

I [wrote a blog post](https://www.novoda.com/blog/accessibilitools/) explaining how you can do it with (and without) a library I helped write. The section under "actions dialog" is the relevant bit.

Answer (score 0):

A button is actionable. If you want your users to be able to do the actions of each button, they need to be separately focusable. If they aren't actionable, they shouldn't be buttons.